# Selenium Grid Video Recording

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, video-recording

I'm trying to record videos of my Selenium-Tests. These Tests run parallel on Selenium Grid.
I wanted to open a VNC-Server for each firefox and then start recording. So one grid-node would open 5 vncservers and then a program like 'recordMyDesktop' would record each one of them and store them in a different file.

I found this: http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/castro-selenium-video.html
but not for Java and Grid...

Thank you in advance

Richard
(My environment is Firefox on Linux)

Comment: why don't you take screenshots? that's a lot cheaper and as useful...

Answer (score 3):

Available since April 2014, there is a java library you can use to record videos called selenium-video-node.

From the README:

> This project adds video recording capability to a Selenium Grid.
>   Videos are encoded into WebM/VP8 format on-the-fly and made available
>   at the end of the test

https://github.com/aimmac23/selenium-video-node